# Empty author field in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I need to add a reference with an empty author field to my bibliography list.
I have this bibitem :

```
@misc{impl,
    title="Abc Def",
    howpublished = {2}
}
```

When I do this I see a colon in front of the reference in my generated pdf file.
I.e, the reference looks like

```
:Abc Def. 2
```

The colon is inserted because it should separate author's name from the title.
Is there any way to get rid of the colon?

I tried to change title to author in my bibitem:

```
@misc{impl,
    author="Abc Def",
    howpublished = {2}
}
```

Unfortunately it shortens the Abc Def to A.Def automatically in the pdf file. (Ie., it considers Abc as somebody's first name).

I'm using a special bibliography style called `splncs`.

Comment: Does the following help: `author={{Abc Def}}` (with double braces)?

Comment: Oleg's advice should work, but if you actually want to publish in LNCS you should rethink this reference. There is a reason why both author and title are required fields of `misc`.

Comment: Oleg's suggestion works, thanks. I actually want to publish a system paper in LNCS. I have a link to my implementation(which also has some other systems) and I'm not sure if I should refer to myself as an author or figure out the full list of authors.  Author is no longer required in misc starting from mybib 0.99d (At least I do not see any warnings from easychair's pdflatex). Maybe I will move the link inside the paper.

Comment: If you have too many names in a list, you may truncate it with 'and others': `author={YourName and AnotherName and others}`. I think it's not a bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

To make `BibTeX` consider some text as a single token (and so keep it unchanged), put it in braces. In your case this will be: `author = {{Abc Def}}.`
This also helps, if you need to preserve the capitalization of some text.