# When author field is empty, do not put colon after prenote in authortitle-comp

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Preemptive note: This is not a duplicate of [Empty author field in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119922).

---

I am experiencing a weird thing with the *authortitle-comp* citation style where, if the *author* field is empty in a bibliographic record, a colon will still be set between the *prenote* field and the *title* field, like in footnote 2, where I'd expect the same behavior as in footnote 1:

[image: Both footnote 1 and 2 should have "Vgl." without the colon in footnote 2]

Here's a minimum working example (never mind the umlauts and such):

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@Incollection{poppe,
    Title = {Die Verwandlung},
    Author = {Sandra Poppe},
    Booktitle = {Kafka-Handbuch},
    Booksubtitle = {Leben -- Werk -- Wirkung},
    Editor = {Manfred Engel and Bernd Auerochs},
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Publisher = {Metzler},
    Year = {2010},
    Pages = {164--174}
}

@Incollection{kindlerbio,
    Title = {Kafka, Franz -- Biogramm},
    Booktitle = {Kindlers Literatur Lexikon in 18 Bänden},
    Publisher = {Metzler},
    Year = {2009},
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Edition = {3., völlig neu bearb. Aufl.},
    Url = {http://www.munzinger.de/document/22000340100},
    Urldate = {2014-07-11}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text,\footfullcite[Vgl.][]{poppe} and some other text as well.\footfullcite[Vgl.][]{kindlerbio}
\end{document}
```

I've been using some additional specifications in a biblatex.cfg file to tweak things according to how my department likes us to format bibliographies, cf. http://pastebin.com/1uZs4vtw (based on [these modifications of authortitle-icomp for German studies](http://j-mach-wust.users.sourceforge.net/de/germanistik-latex.html) by J. 'Mach' Wust). Without that file, things are generated as expected except there's a full stop after the author name instead of a colon, and further testing reveals that the following line is the culprit (this is a change that is suggested e.g. in [Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex, alphabetic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/), maybe the original author copied it from there, I don't know):

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
```

If it's that, how would this line have to be changed to not result in the problem I have? Changing this line to

```
\renewcommand{\nametitledelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
```

does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Just an aside: For `kindlerbio` the entry type `@inreference` might be more fitting than `@incollection` (in the standard styles though currently, the former is an alias for the latter). A `@reference` refers to "A [...] work of reference such as an encyclopedia or a dictionary."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to lie with `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker.
Since `author` is a required field for `@incollection`s, `biblatex` can - in a way - expect there to be one. (As a matter of fact, that is not the best of ideas, especially since `@incollection` is alias for `@inreference` in the standard styles, and `@inreference` entries don't always have authors one can easily find out about.)

So we will have to deal with the punctuation tracker and tell it not to print any colons, this can be done in two ways:

### Use `\nopunct`

We can reformat the `prenote` field to

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1\isdot\nopunct}
```

This will always add `\nopunct` after the field, therefore suppressing any punctuation that might come directly after the `prenote` field (in some cases that superfluous colon; in most cases it will do absolutely nothing.)

### Use `\printunit` instead of `\setunit`

The `prenote` macro uses `\setunit` to print the `\prenotedelim` - the delimiter between the prenote and the citation proper - by default this is a space.
We can modify the macro to use `\printunit` instead.

```
\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \printunit{\prenotedelim}}}
```

`biblatex` employs this highly sophisticated punctuation tracker mechanism in order to make sure no superfluous punctuation is printed.
If one uses the proper punctuation commands `\setunit` and friends, the punctuation is not printed immediately, it is merely stored in a "buffer" and printed when needed next - `biblatex` inserts punctuation before a field is printed.

Subsequent `\setunit`s override each other so `\setunit{A}\setunit{B}\setunit{C}` will put `A` in the buffer, then overwrite it with `B` and then with `C`; so if punctuation is called for the next time (and no other command alters the buffer) "C" is printed.

With `\printunit` the punctuation is not overridden by a subsequent punctuation command, but persist in the buffer unit it is printed or reset by special commands.

The problem here was that the `\prenotedelim` was not actually printed until the next command printed anything, said command in the problematic case printed the `title` field, at which point the punctuation buffer had been overwritten with `\labelnamepunct` causing `biblatex` to print the colon.
In the non-problematic case, the next command to print something was the `author` macro - no new punctuation had been inserted into the buffer at this point, so the `\prenotedelim` was printed as expected.

You can read more about this in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker*, pp. 238-242 and §4.7.1 *Block and Unit Punctuation*, pp. 197 seq.

This problem is not visible if we don't redefine the `\labelnamepunct`. By default it is the same as `\newunitpunct`, which in turn defaults to `\addperiod\space`. `biblatex` is clever and avoids double periods/dots, it treats the "." at the end of "Vgl." as an abbreviation dot (thanks to the standard `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1\isdot}` definition) so that it does not print "Vgl..", but "Vgl." - it suppresses the period inserted by `\setunit`; a dot-colon construct is possible though, so with a colon we get "Vgl.:" and the colon is not suppressed.

### MWE

I feel that using `\printunit` is the more appropriate solution in this case, choose what you like best.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Incollection{poppe,
    Title = {Die Verwandlung},
    Author = {Sandra Poppe},
    Booktitle = {Kafka-Handbuch},
    Booksubtitle = {Leben -- Werk -- Wirkung},
    Editor = {Manfred Engel and Bernd Auerochs},
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Publisher = {Metzler},
    Year = {2010},
    Pages = {164--174}
}

@inreference{kindlerbio,
    Title = {Kafka, Franz -- Biogramm},
    Booktitle = {Kindlers Literatur Lexikon in 18 Bänden},
    Publisher = {Metzler},
    Year = {2009},
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Edition = {3., völlig neu bearb. Aufl.},
    Url = {http://www.munzinger.de/document/22000340100},
    Urldate = {2014-07-11}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \printunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\begin{document}
Some text,\footfullcite[Vgl.][]{poppe} and some other text as well.\footfullcite[Vgl.][]{kindlerbio}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]